# How to expose a service running inside a docker container, bound to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a service running inside a docker-container, which by default only binds to localhost.

I could reconfigure / reprogram this service to bind to all interfaces, but this might have security implications in other contexts. Is there any way to expose a service bound to localhost inside a docker container?

Comment: I was going to suggest `iptables` with `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` but it appears there are some issues with DNAT in the container name space

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using socat inside the docker container, to proxy any tcp connections on the relevant port-number coming in on the public interface, to the private interface.

For example, this can be added to the docker-container run-script to proxy a service bound on localhost:3000 to the :3000, where it can be EXPOSED and --linked like any other service. Make sure to install socat inside the container.

`` socat TCP4-LISTEN:3000,bind=`hostname -I | tr -d '[:space:]'`,fork TCP4:localhost:3000 & ``

Please note; I am using `hostname -I | tr -d '[:space:]'` to discover the ip of the docker container. Since normally docker containers have only one public ip, this works well.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me for the AWS' SSM  session-manager-plugin running inside a docker container to expose the tunnel created by `aws ssm start-session --target "${ec2_instance_id}" --document-name "AWS-StartPortForwardingSession"`