# How to reach docker container `localhost` from Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-network

Note this is different from [How to expose a service running inside a docker container, bound to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383804), which can be addressed in multiple ways in Docker for Linux, say through `--net host` or even `-v` to bind my Linux-flavor client in etc. My problem is specific for Docker for Mac, so it's not as straightforward.

I have a TCP server binding to `localhost:5005` running inside Docker for Mac. (For security reason, I must not bind to `0.0.0.0:5005`.)

I have a TCP client sending request to this server from my Mac (not inside the docker container).

My question is, how do I make it work?

In Linux Docker, I would simply use `--net=host` so the server binds to my host `lo` interface, but it seems that Docker for Mac runs on a managed VM, so the `host` network behavior is different behavior.

To illustrate my point:

**On MacBook**

It simply would not work

```
[me@MacBook App]$ docker run -v `pwd`:/App -p 127.0.0.1:5005:5005 nitincypher/docker-ubuntu-python-pip /App/server.py
[me@MacBook App]$ ./client.py 
Client received data:
```

**On Linux**

In comparison, it would be trivial to do on Linux by using `host` network mode. Since I'm using my Linux's `lo` interface as my container `lo` interface.

```
[me@Linux App]$ docker run -v `pwd`:/App --net=host nitincypher/docker-ubuntu-python-pip /App/server.py
Server Connection address: ('127.0.0.1', 52172)
Server received data: Hello, World!
[me@Linux App]$ ./client.py 
Client received data: Hello, World!
```

**My Simulated Server Code**

Requirement: It MUST bind to `localhost`, and nothing else. So I cannot change it to `0.0.0.0`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Server Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "Server received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

**My Simulated Client Code**

Requirement: It MUST be ran on MacBook, since the real client is written in CPP and compiled to run only on MacBook.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "Client received data:", data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expose a service running inside a docker container, bound to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383804/how-to-expose-a-service-running-inside-a-docker-container-bound-to-localhost)

Comment: To a first approximation, programs that bind(2) to `localhost` running in Docker containers are unreachable from anywhere (except other processes in a multi-process container, or other containers in the some Kubernetes Pod).  You can ask Docker to only allow host connections from `localhost` (`-p 127.0.0.1:5005:5005`), but the program inside the container needs to allow connections from the Docker bridge at the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working solution. The basic idea is to use SSH tunneling to do the port forwarding.

## High Level Idea

- You first need to build a docker image to support SSH access, because

  1. `ubuntu` image doesn't have a `sshd` out of box, and also
  2. you will need to know the password of `root` of your running container.
- Then you will spin up your container as what you would normally do except that you are doing that based on the new image you created.
- You create a SSH tunneling session from your MacBook, then you run your client on MacBook as you would normally do.

For reference, the command for [SSH tunneling](https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) can be found here, the process of creating a sshd docker image is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191297/3806343), and how to ssh into docker container is [explained here](https://superuser.com/a/1080211/708253)

## Steps

1. Create a Docker file `Dockerfile`

   ```
   #Use whatever image you are using on Docker Linux , say "FROM ubuntu:16.04"
   FROM nitincypher/docker-ubuntu-python-pip

   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
   RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
   RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
   RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

   # SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
   RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

   ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
   RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

   EXPOSE 22
   CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
   ```
2. Create a Docker Image from the Dockerfile

   ```
   [me@MacBook App]$ docker build -t my_ssh_python .
   ```
3. Spin up your server container

   ```
   [me@MacBook App]$ docker run -d -P -v `pwd`:/App --name myserver my_ssh_python
   ```
4. Start your server inside the container

   ```
   [me@MacBook App]$ docker exec myserver /App/server.py
   ```
5. Create a SSH tunnel

   ```
   [me@MacBook App]$ ssh root@`hostname` -p `docker port myserver 22 | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'` -L 8000:localhost:8000 -N
   #Password is "screencast" as you built in Dockerfile
   ```

   Note that

   a. You have to use the IP address of your MacBook instead of your docker container's IP address.

   b. You will use the port where the default container `ssh` port `22` is mapped to on host

   c. In tunneling `-L 8000:localhost:8000`, you are saying forward anything from your MacBook `8000` (the first 8000) to Docker container's `localhost` at port `8000`
6. Now you can use you client locally

   ```
   [me@MacBook App]$ ./client.py 
   Client received data: Hello, World!
   ```

   And on server side, you can see

   ```
   Server Connection address: ('127.0.0.1', 55396)
   Server received data: Hello, World!
   ```